# Principle Component Analysis using Python

Tags: python

Here, [image: figure of my data] is the example of 2D scatter data
but when I draw the eigenvectors,
the plot is compressed into 1D image [image: like this].

I'm trying to do PCA on a temperature and strain data.

Why I have a 1D vector of the combination of the scattering and plotting the eigen vector ?

```
def process_data_PCA(temperature, strain):
    print("process data")
    T1 = temperature['T1'].tolist()
    T2 = temperature['T2'].tolist()
    T3 = temperature['T3'].tolist()
    T4 = temperature['T4'].tolist()
    T5 = temperature['T5'].tolist()
    T6 = temperature['T6'].tolist()
    T7 = temperature['T7'].tolist()
    T8 = temperature['T8'].tolist()
    T9 = temperature['T9'].tolist()
    T10 = temperature['T10'].tolist()

    W_A1 = strain[0]
    N = len(T1)
    xData =  T1
    yData =  W_A1
    xData = np.reshape(xData, (N, 1))
    yData = np.reshape(yData, (N, 1))

    data = np.hstack((xData, yData))
    print(data)
    mu = data.mean(axis=0)
    data = data - mu
    # data = (data - mu)/data.std(axis=0)  # Uncommenting this reproduces mlab.PCA results
    eigenvectors, eigenvalues, V = np.linalg.svd(data.T, full_matrices=False)
    projected_data = np.dot(data, eigenvectors)
    sigma = projected_data.std(axis=0).mean()
    print(eigenvectors)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(xData, yData, s= 0.1)
    for axis in eigenvectors:
        start, end = mu, mu + sigma * axis
        ax.annotate(
            '', xy=end, xycoords='data',
            xytext=start, textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='red', width=2.0))
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    plt.show()
```

print(data)

```
[[14.25        0.        ]
 [14.25        0.        ]
 [14.26        0.        ]
 ...
 [12.51       -0.02470534]
 [12.51       -0.02540376]
 [12.52       -0.02542746]]
[[-0.99999927 -0.00120856]
 [-0.00120856  0.99999927]]
```

eigenvectors
[-0.99999927 -0.00120856]
[-0.00120856  0.99999927]

start, end

```
 1.95096698e+01 -5.70968943e-03] [ 1.7057429e+01 -8.6733643e-03]
[ 1.95096698e+01 -5.70968943e-03] [19.50670611  2.44653112]
```

Comment: can you show what is output of `print(data)` and `print(eigenvectors)`?

Comment: Are you using PCA in a correct way for your data?  I mean, you only take T1  as your xdata and then the strain as ydata. As we do not know the array sizes, I do not know if the output is wrong or not.

Comment: @hadik I printed the data

Comment: @msi_gerva The array size are the same of both x,y data

Comment: @msi_gerva both are 60000

Comment: I would suggest printing out start and end after line `start, end = mu, mu + sigma * axis` to check whether the values are changing. I tried with random numbers (`data=np.random.random((60000,2))`) and if I try to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for data.T without full matrices, I got only  2 eigenvalues and 2 eigenvectors.

Comment: @msi_gerva I have printed it, look at the post

Comment: What will happen with the figure if you do not use `ax.set_aspect('equal')`?

Comment: with data=np.random.random((60000,2))),  I get one dimensoal vector, the same as the graph in the post

Comment: @msi_gerva without set_aspect, I get the following image, but the second orthognal vector is now shown https://imgur.com/a/XUaXKOZ

Comment: I have a feeling that I do not understand what you want to plot. Do you want to plot 2 vectors on top of your scatter plot or something else? The thing is that if you look at the values of x-axis and y-axis - one varies from 10 to 20 and the second varies from some -0.0X to 0.0Y... If you plot 4 vectors, where 3 of them start at 1X and end in 0.0X and 1 which start from 19.5 and ends in 2.44 you are supposed to see most likely 2 vectors and 1 horisontal line (the scatter points as the values in Y-direction do not vary much).

Comment: @msi_gerva yes that's what I want to do exactly

Comment: I suppose the annotation command is not used correctly. Why don't you use quiver method instead for plotting vectors?

Comment: @msi_gerva Can you propose a solution with an answer ?

Comment: @andreahmed can you plot :  `x = [eigvec[0][0] + xmean ,eigvec[1][0] + xmean ] ;y =  [eigvec[0][1] + ymean ,eigvec[1][1] + ymean ]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I tested you code and I think a main problem for you is the line `sigma = projected_data.std(axis=0).mean()`, to look at the scatter in the respective eigendirection, you do not need the `mean()` but you need both values of `std` in both eigendirection. So just remove the mean to `sigma = projected_data.std(axis=0)` and you get good pca plot. I tested it below with some pseudorandom number.

```
#data = np.hstack((xData, yData))
N = 8000
data = np.random.random((N,2))
########################################################################
# Random number in Ellipse
########################################################################
a = 0.5
b = 0.15
a2 = a**2
b2 = b**2
cx = 0.5
cy = 0.5
xData = []
yData = []
for i in range(N):
    if ((data[i,0]-cx)**2/a2+(data[i,1]-cy)**2/b2 -1.)<0:
        xData.append(data[i,0])
        yData.append(data[i,1])
##################################################
xData = np.array(xData)
yData = np.array(yData)
data = np.vstack((xData, yData)).T

mu = data.mean(axis=0)

data = data - mu
# data = (data - mu)/data.std(axis=0)  # Uncommenting this reproduces mlab.PCA results
eigenvectors, eigenvalues, V = np.linalg.svd(data.T, full_matrices=False)
projected_data = np.dot(data, eigenvectors)
print np.shape(projected_data)
############################################################
#sigma = projected_data.std(axis=0).mean()
# In this line, mean is removed
sigma = projected_data.std(axis=0)
############################################################
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
ax.scatter(xData, yData, s= 0.1)
ax.scatter(mu[0],mu[1],s = 50,marker='*', c = 'r')
for axis,s in zip(eigenvectors,sigma):
    #start, end = mu, mu + sigma * axis
    start, end = mu, mu + s * axis
    ax.annotate(
        '', xy=end, xycoords='data',
        xytext=start, textcoords='data',
        arrowprops=dict(facecolor='red', width=2.0))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.savefig("pcs.png")
plt.show()

#print eigenvalues
```

How it looks like now.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked. Do you how to model the data and predict the strain from the temperature ? any information on how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the problem in your case is the limit of the axes. The annotation does not update the information of axes limits and the plot uses only the limits of the data (scatter plot on the image).

I was able to produce manually the plot you wanted with the code (function plot_andre).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
import numpy as np
from pylab import plt
# ---------------------------------------------
np.random.seed(0);
# ---------------------------------------------
def process_data_PCA():
    print("process data")
    T1=np.random.random((60000,1));
    W_A1=np.random.random((60000,1));

    N = len(T1)
    xData =  T1
    yData =  W_A1
    xData = np.reshape(xData, (N, 1))
    yData = np.reshape(yData, (N, 1))

    data = np.hstack((xData, yData))
    print(data)
    mu = data.mean(axis=0)
    data = data - mu
    # data = (data - mu)/data.std(axis=0)  # Uncommenting this reproduces mlab.PCA results
    eigenvectors, eigenvalues, V = np.linalg.svd(data.T, full_matrices=False)
    projected_data = np.dot(data, eigenvectors)
    sigma = projected_data.std(axis=0).mean()
    print(eigenvectors)
    # ----------------------------------------
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(xData, yData, s= 0.1)
    for axis in eigenvectors:
        start, end = mu, mu + sigma * axis
        ax.annotate(
            '', xy=end, xycoords='data',
            xytext=start, textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='red', width=2.0))
        # ------------------------------------
        print start,end
    # ----------------------------------------
    ax.set_aspect('equal');#plt.axis('tight');
    plt.savefig('test_01.png',bbox_inches='tight');
    plt.show()
# -----------------------------------
def plot_andre():
    # ----------------------------------------
    vectors=[[[1.95096698e+01,-5.70968943e-03],[ 1.7057429e+01,-8.6733643e-03]],[[ 1.95096698e+01,-5.70968943e-03],[19.50670611,2.44653112]]];
    # ----------------------------------------
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for iax in range(len(vectors)):
        start,end=vectors[iax];
        ax.annotate(
            '', xy=end, xycoords='data',
            xytext=start, textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='red', width=2.0))
    # ----------------------------------------
    vectors=np.array(vectors);
    ax.set_xlim(np.min(vectors[:,0]),np.max(vectors[:,0]));ax.set_ylim(np.min(vectors[:,1]),np.max(vectors[:,1]));
    ax.set_aspect('equal');#plt.axis('tight');
    plt.savefig('test_02.png',bbox_inches='tight');
    plt.show()

# -----------------------------------
process_data_PCA();
plot_andre();
```

Just set the axes limits to some suitable values like 0-20 and 0-20.

Comment: how to import cvs file and analysis it?